# how to deselect other rows once selected a row in javascript?

Tags: javascript, select, row

I have a table with user information.
I want to select one row (an object) and show the select icon and once I select one row, I would like to deselect other row(previous selected row) 
However, with my code, the selection rows are accumulated if not selecting row again.

The code I created :

```
  this.selectRow = function (row) {

  if (this.isClickable()) {
  $scope.properties.selectedRow = row;
  }
  if (row.selected === undefined)
    row.selected = false;
    row.selected = !row.selected;  

 }; 

 this.isSelected = function(row) { 
 return angular.equals(row, $scope.properties.selectedRow) ;
 };
```

and HTML table is :

```
<tbody ng-if="ctrl.isArray(properties.content) && ctrl.isArray(properties.columnsKey)">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in properties.content" ng-click="ctrl.selectRow(row)" ng-class="{'info': ctrl.isSelected(row)}">
            <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-show="row.selected"></span></td>
             <td ng-if="!properties.allowHTML" ng-repeat="column in properties.columnsKey track by $index">
                {{ $eval(column, row) | uiTranslate }}
            </td>
            <td ng-if="properties.allowHTML" ng-repeat="column in properties.columnsKey track by $index">
                <div ng-if="properties.allowHTML" ng-bind-html="$eval(column, row) | uiTranslate"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

It seems working properly, I could select and deselect row and the icon show hide properly.
however, I need to deselect the row I already selected before.

The selected row object is :

{
  "userName": "user1",
  "userId": "23",
  "selected": true
}
{
  "userName": "user1",
  "userId": "23",
  "selected": false
}

Any help would be appreciate 
Thank you.

Comment: If your rows have a class you could deselect all rows before selecting the one you clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i am resetting the previous selected row. I am setting its property to false.

```js
this.selectRow = function(row) {
  // if row is already selected, deselect it.
  if (row.selected) {
    row.selected = false;
  } else {
    // find the row which was previously selected.
    const isRowSelected = $scope.properties.content.filter((item) => item.selected === true);
    if (isRowSelected.length > 0) {
      // if row found successfully, mark that row as deselected
      $scope.properties.content.filter((item) => item.selected === true)[0].selected = false;
    }
    // mark new row as selected
    row.selected = true;
  }

  if (this.isClickable()) {
    $scope.properties.selectedRow = row;
  }
  if (row.selected === undefined) {
    row.selected = false;
  }
};

this.isSelected = function(row) {
  return angular.equals(row, $scope.properties.selectedRow);
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I could not get the proper function.
I got the error 

vendor.min.js:105 TypeError: Cannot set property 'selected' of undefined
    at PbTableCtrl.selectRow (widgets-16134b44d7c68b34a05a2d137b1a162aad6e7028.min.js:2)
    at vendor.min.js:203
    at f (vendor.min.js:220)
    at m.$eval (vendor.min.js:129)
    at m.$apply (vendor.min.js:129)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.<anonymous> (vendor.min.js:220)
    at HTMLTableRowElement.c (vendor.min.js:35)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you please create angular js fiddle, it would be easy for me to understand your problem.

Comment: Apologies for inconvenience, I have updated the code. I am resetting the row selected value to false if there is a row with selected value of true.

It is very difficult to fix a bug without seeing it. Just a request if the current implementation does not fix the issue, please create a basic working demo showing issue.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying to create a js fiddle. 
I am going to test and update as possible as I can.
Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, please check it thoroughly and let me know if it resolves your issue. If it doesn't then please make a jsfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, I am not able to resolve the issue. Also, it is a Bonita bpm UI custom widget. It communicates between UI form and custom widget of Bonita UI designer.  I have no idea how to create JS fiddle either. I am sorry about that. By any chance, are you able to open the code by Bonita UI designer? Anyhow I appreciate your help. Many thanks :)

Comment: I updated the code yesterday, did not it resolve the issue ?

Comment: Oh, I need to explain more.  Yes, I updated the code you updated yesterday. It works well.  But I wanted that if I click the row one time, selected return true, then, if I click again, selected return false like.

if (row.selected === undefined)
    row.selected = false;
    row.selected = !row.selected;  
 }; 

My issue was the selected rows are accumulated. it solved by your help. However, I want to select and deselect if I click the same row again. 

I am sorry for the vague explains. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: give me some time, i will update the code the code again incorporating your new request.

Comment: Done, you can check now. I have updated the code as per your new request.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It works perfectly. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: No youries. I would suggest to create jsfiddle from next time as it would be helpful for all of us and for you as well. Thanks!